# How can I do a Login Form using three layer architecture and SQL server?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I have to do a Login form with Java, using three layer architecture and a database, I'm using SQL Server.

In my DA class I have this code: Basically what I'm trying to do is to send the jText user and jText password to the setPassword and setUser from the BL class.

```
    u.setLogin(jtxtUsuario.getText());
    u.setContrasenia(jtxtPassword.getText());
    DA.DB.getConexion();
    if (DA.DB.getStatus()) {
         new jfrmInterno().setVisible(true);
    }else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre de usuario ingresado no coincide con ninguna cuenta","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jtxtUsuario.setText("");
        jtxtPassword.setText("");
    }
```

In my BL class I have this code: In the method "validarUsuario" im sending the user and pass to the "setUsuario" method in the DA class.

```
public void setLogin(String login) {
    if(login != null && login.length() > 3) {
        _login = login;
    }else {
        _login = "Usuario Incorrecto";
    }
}

public String getLogin() {
    return _login;
}

public void setContrasenia(String contrasenia) {
    if(contrasenia != null && contrasenia.length() > 6) {
        _contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }else {
        _contrasenia = "Contraseña Incorrecta";
    }
}

public String getContrasenia() {
    return _contrasenia;
}

public void validarUsuario() {
    admin.setUsuario(getLogin(), getContrasenia());
}

public Colegio() {
    this("","");
}    

public Colegio(String login, String contrasenia) {
    setLogin(login);
    setContrasenia(contrasenia);
}
```

}

The problem I have is in the DA class, I dont know how I can use the jText user and password and validate it against the user and password I have in the DB from the DA class. I create a method in the DA class called "setUsuario" which receives the user and password from the jText, but after that I dont know what else I can do, the idea is if the user and password are correct it should open a new Jframe.

```
public static Connection getConexion() {
    status = false;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Colegio";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo establecer conexión");
    }
    try {
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Login] where NombreUsuario=? AND Contrasenia=?");
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        status = true;
    }catch (SQLException e) {

    }
    return cn;
}

public void setUsuario(String user, String pass) {
    DB.user = user;
    DB.pass = pass;
}
```

Comment: You can directly pass values to `setUsuario` and then call the `getConexion()` method

Answer (score 0):

In your DA class, you have to check if there is a record exists or not in the database like this,

```
public static boolean getConexion() { // change it to boolean because it returns boolean value
    status = false;

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Colegio";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo establecer conexión");
    }

    try {
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Login] where NombreUsuario=? AND Contrasenia=?");
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next) {
           status = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
    return status;
}

public void setUsuario(String user, String pass) {
    DB.user = user;
    DB.pass = pass;
}
```

And in your view, you can pass the values to `setUsuario()` method and then call the `getConexion()` method which returns `true` if the user exists as shown below,

```
DA.DB.setUsuario(jtxtUsuario.getText(), jtxtPassword.getText());
if (DA.DB.getConexion()) {
     new jfrmInterno().setVisible(true);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre de usuario ingresado no coincide con ninguna cuenta","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    jtxtUsuario.setText("");
    jtxtPassword.setText("");
}
```

And I can't see the `DA.DB.getStatus()` method, so I have coded inside the `getConexion()` method to show what you are missing and this is not a **GOOD PRACTICE** to code inside the Database Connection and it should be in a separate class.